# Error in a resource

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Sorry, the error is another one. It is in the ImageButton. But the issue is fixed now.
That's why I change it for R.id.none. But when I change it for the right name, I thought it wouldn't run but it runs. Very strange.

```
    imgbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.none);

    imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Toast.makeText(Insertarlugar.this, "ImageButton is clicked!", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }

    });
}

    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.insertarlugar, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Comment: Post the logcat output please.

Comment: `imgbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.none);` and then `imgbutton.setOnClickListener`... are You sure you named your ImageButton none?

Comment: Also, when making questions, try to attach only the necessary code. Few will want to read through all of it, and the fact that you just copy-paste everything indicates you've done little research to solve your problem

Comment: @Jaguar.  NPEs are nothing to do with Android, they are thrown by the Java runtime and they are no more common than in any object oriented language.  Declare a reference to an object, don't instantiate it then try to dereference it.  Boom.  c#, Object Pascal, Objective C etc, they all have them.

Comment: Clean your project then rebuild.